# iPhone: How Can I Dial to a Phone Number Without Quitting My Application?

Tags: iphone

On the iPhone, how can I dial to a phone number without quitting my application?
Right now my program can trigger a call to a specific phone number but doing so causes my app to quit. How can I make a call in the background or otherwise make a call without quitting my application?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the official SDK.

Comment: I don't think this question requires a downvote. It is a legit question.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The iPhone simply doesn't allow this.

Comment: Yes, and the reason is simple. All other functions on the iPhone are subordinated to the need to keep the phone function utterly reliable. because someone cannot make a phone call in an emergency, it could result in death. There are also security and privacy concerns if an app could stealthy make calls.